# Model not being executed on Multiple GPUs when using Huggingface Seq2SeqTrainer with accelerate

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, distributed-training, accelerate

I have a setup with a single node having 8 A100 GPUs.

- python = 3.8.10
- torch==2.0.1+cu117
- accelerate==0.26.1
- CUDA Version: 11.7

I am using AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM to load a model for finetuning and use Seq2SeqTrainer. The dataset is copied to multiple GPUs but the model is not being copied (as seen from memory usage using nvidia-smi). Could someone please explain what am I missing for DDP? I can see that 8 different losses are calculated during validation in logs. I am not able to find out why the computation is not being shared as the GPU utilization for 7 GPUs stays zero.

Code:

```
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint, cache_dir=cache_dir,torch_dtype='torch.bfloat16', device_map='auto')

num_gpus = torch.cuda.device_count()

args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
     output_dir=f"/outdir",
     evaluation_strategy=“epoch”,
     learning_rate=learning_rate,
     per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size//num_gpus,
     per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size//num_gpus,
     weight_decay=0.01,
     save_total_limit=1,
     num_train_epochs=num_train_epochs,
     predict_with_generate=True,
     logging_steps=logging_steps,
     push_to_hub=False,
    )
trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
     model,
     args,
     train_dataset=tokenized_datasets[“train”],
     eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets[“validation”].select(range(32)),
     data_collator=data_collator,
     tokenizer=tokenizer,
     compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    )
```

[image: nvidia-smi output]

Comment: Starting the training using `torchrun` and specifying `nproc_per_node ` made it run with DDP as expected. `torchrun --nproc_per_node 8 <trainingfile.py>` . However, I got Out of Memory errors for the GPU after around 20% training. I additionally added arguments split_batches=True and gradient_checkpointing=True to make the training work. Starting the training with just python <trainingfile.py> (as in ques. above) should do a training with DP. But I am not sure why the memory usage is so low in this case on the other GPUs and the utilisation stays at zero when seen with `nvidia-smi`.